# (Cake)PHP - Updating child databases with data from master

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm developing an application using CakePHP (latest version) framework for PHP that will unite several instalations of a CMS with a single registration form. I'm using a MySql DB. The problem is that I cannot modify the CMS code, I can only modify the DB data since very frequent CMS updates will overwrite my modifications.

The idea is that the system will keep a master Users table as shown in the diagram with the shared data. The table model of the master Users table and the child Users table is the same, except for a few CMS installation specific columns (as shown in the simplified diagram).

Now I'm trying to figure out a way to reflect the changes I do on master (INSERT and UPDATE) to occur on all of the child DBs. So when I make a change in my CakePHP app I want those fields that are shared to be updated in all child DB instances.

[image: Diagram (can't post images yet, sorry)]

One solution would be to write manual MySQL queries for every single action in the application but that seems redundant and annoying.

How could I make my app to repeat all of the queries I do on my MASTER on every CHILD. Basicly if I UPDATE the name of entry ID 5 in MASTER, that that same query is ran on all of the child databases (which will hold the same entry under the same ID but with a few additional columns).

Comment: I did not fully appreciate the issues that were trying to be solved so i deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easily with CakePHP's model triggers (beforeSave, afterSave...) BUT keeping all that stuff synchronized will soon become your worst nightmare. Instead, I would do something like this:

- Master.User has (id, name, password, specData1, specData2...)
- Child1.User is a mysql VIEW: `CREATE VIEW User AS SELECT id AS id, name AS name.., specData1 AS specData FROM Master.User`

Yes, you can create cross-DB views. For the CMSs Child1.User is a table, all operations CREATE/DELETE/UPDATE are transparently done by the CMS on the VIEW thinking its a table. (but Master.User gets updated)

Comment: I will look into the view idea, seems cool. But the thing is, it is not supposed to sync the specData column (specData is not even in the MASTER DB), specData is the field which contents differ from CHILD DB to CHILD DB. That is the field that is very important to be kept individual for every child. I will look into it tho, I hope something like this is possible.

Comment: All specData (from all CHILD DBs) are keps in the Master.User. The reason is that splitting the Child.User table will cause more problems. But please read carefully. For `Child1.User(specData) -> the VIEW is Master.User(specData1) AS specData` and so on. Notice `1`. For `Child2.User` is `Master.User.specData2 AS specData` Individual child specData fields are kept in Master.User.

Comment: Umhum, I'm afraid that won't really do then. The number of installations is dynamic, it can change from week to week. And modifying the table structure and creating views every time a new installation is created would be a bit dangerous.